# What is 'app key' in GCM Notification sample?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, google-cloud-messaging, google-chrome-app

I am trying to run this official [GCM Notifications sample](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/chrome-app-samples/tree/master/gcm-notifications). This comes with no instructions so trying to figure out on my own.

Here is what I did:

- Registered an app on Google Dev Console, enabled APIs for `Google+ API`, `Google Cloud Messaging for Android` and `Google Cloud Messaging for Chrome`
- I downloaded the repo and removed 'Key' field from the `manifest.json`
- I uploaded it under my chrome app developers account
- I installed this app. And opened the extension location and copied `key` field from `manifest.json`
- Opened the Chrome app. Used the project id of app I registered on dev console as `Sender ID`. After pressing `Register` it said: 'Registration succeeded. Run the following command to send a message.'
- Now it has three fields `App Key`, `Message Key` and `Message Value`. So in `App key` I entered `key` which I got from `manifest.json` and in both fields of `Message Key` and `Message Value` I entered `Test` and `Hello world` respectively.
- It gave me a command like:

  ```
  curl -H "Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8" -H "Authorization: key=Mg...AB" -d "registration_id=AP...tQ" -d data.test=hello https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send
  ```

When I run this from my local machine, I am getting following error:

```
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<TITLE>Unauthorized</TITLE>
</HEAD>
<BODY BGCOLOR="#FFFFFF" TEXT="#000000">
<H1>Unauthorized</H1>
<H2>Error 401</H2>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "Authorization: key" is not the key in the manifest.json file. It is the API key, which you get from the Developers Console. (Leave a comment if you can't find the API key, and I'll provide more detailed instructions.)

As the API has evolved into what is now the GCM API, the terminology has changed, and its usage by Google is inconcistent.